Which term is more appropriate for the name of our organization: ‘Uzenergy Inspection’ or ‘Uzenergy Inspectorate’?”
Our organization is a state body responsible for overseeing compliance with legislation in the energy sector, including monitoring the use of electricity, petroleum products, and gas, preventing illegal connections, and promoting energy efficiency. We are debating whether ‘Uzenergy Inspection’ or ‘Uzenergy Inspectorate’ better reflects our role and scope of responsibilities. Which would you recommend and why?

I’m voting to close this question because naming things is off topic.

To think Linguistics Stack Exchange could have been responsible for naming Uzbekistan’s energy compliance organisation. Sadly this is well and truly off-topic.
